# How can I display photo regardless of the extension

Tags: php, image, jpeg, display

I made a php code that displays the photo in .jpg format.

```
echo '<a href="2000/images/'.$alias.'/'.$peaks_list[$x].'.jpg" target="_blank">}'.$peaks_list[$x].'</a>';
```

`$alias` and `peaks_list[$x]` are variables from the database and everything works. The problem is if someone uploads a photo in **.JPG** format. How to write a code to display a photo if it's in **.jpg** or **.JPG** format

Edit: Image extension is not saved in the database. The database contains the names of the users and the names of the mountains. Based on this, we create *link: /&user/$peak.jpg*.

If the user uploads peak.jpg the photo is displayed correctly. If uploaded peak.JPG the photo will not be displayed

Solved with file_exists

```
    if (file_exists('2000/images/'.$alias.'/'.$peaks_list[$x].'.jpg')) {
$ext= ".jpg";} else {
$ext= ".JPG";}
echo '<a {modal href="2000/images/'.$alias.'/'.$peaks_list[$x].''.$ext.'" target="_blank">}'.$peaks_list[$x].'{/modal}</a>';
echo ", ";
```

Thanks, 
Midhat

Comment: Do you save the image type anywhere?

Comment: Save the extension ?

Comment: Or convert the image to the desired type and automatically rename it ?

Comment: *"display a photo if it's in .jpg or .JPG format"* ... lowercase the filename when you do `move_uploaded_file` - before saving it into the database (that way everything is always lowercase)?

Comment: Save the extension as well.

Comment: you have to save files with extension at both places:- in folder as well as in database table record.that's the best practice. Otherwise use `file_exist()` to check and go for `if-else` block

Comment: Post is edited. I will try with file_exist()

Comment: Solved with file_exists. Thanks @AlivetoDie